# Number of neurons in output layer NeuralNetwork

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is it compulsory to have a single neuron in the output layer?
Or is it ok to have multiple neurons in output layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One neuron in the output layer means regression, multiple neurons means classification. Simple as that. An artificial neuron has inherently a continuous value output, therefore regression can be regarded as the natural function of the network where a single output neuron is required. Classification is achieved by means of coding and discretising the network's continuous value output, which is why you need a number of neurons in the output layer equal to the number of your classes.

Comment: How about binary classification? In that case, one neuron should suffice... Which one is more common?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have multiple output neurons in NN if you are solving multiclass classification problem. Otherwise it doesn't make sense, but anyway nothing stops you from having multiple outputs.

Comment: How about binary classification? In that case, one neuron should suffice... Which one is more common?